# reduxForm render before the initialValues request complete

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui, redux-form

I am using the `react`, `material-ui`,`react-router`, `reduxForm` and  `redux`.

In my viewComponent A, I click a button to push to viewComponent B. 
In `componentWillMount` or `componentDidMount` of viewComponent B,, I send a get request.

There is a reduxForm component C in viewComponent B,

Component C with an initialValues of the get request success reduce.

My problem is: 
   There are three buttons in viewComponent A.
When I press the button 1, ReduxForm component C does not have the initialValues.

When I press the button 2, ReduxForm component C does not have the initialValues of button 1.

In my opinion, the ReduxForm render before the request complete.

How to send the initialValues request?  When do i to send the initialValues request?

Comment: can you share some  code

Comment: Yeah, this is too abstract to help you. Even some <A><B><C/></B></A> structure would help here.

Comment: @SumitR The code is a little more.  I might write the code.Thank you.

Comment: @ErikR. Thank you.